# If Felidar Sovereign enters the battlefield during my upkeep, will he trigger?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Given that [Felidar Sovereign](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Felidar%20Sovereign) is being reprinted in Battle for Zendikar, I have a question about the win condition and nobody I know can help. I was hoping someone on here could.

If I am at over 40 life with a Felidar Sovereign in the graveyard and I have a [Sheoldred, Whispering One](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sheoldred%2C%20Whispering%20One) on the battlefield, can I use Sheoldred's ability to bring the Felidar back in my upkeep and win the game?

Comment: "At the beginning of your upkeep" triggers as the Upkeep Step is entered, before Sheoldred's ability is placed on the stack, before Sheoldred's ability  resolves, and before Felidar Sovereign is placed on the battlefield.

Comment: @RyuAkamatsu That was @diego (who also happens to be user who answered your question). By the way, you can tag cards with the syntax `[mtg:Card Name]`. It automatically creates the links for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you will not win the game this turn.

This is because both abilities are triggered abilities with "At the beginning of your upkeep" as the trigger. But the Sovereign is in the graveyard at the beginning of your upkeep so it will not trigger, and after Sheoldred's ability resolves and the Sovereign is one the battlefield it is no longer the beginning of your upkeep so it will not trigger this turn.